# Connecting to OpenVPN Server via Chrome/Firefox Browser

Tags: vpn, google-chrome-extensions, openvpn, firefox-extensions

I'm planning on running a OpenVPN Service on my Raspberry Pi to encrypt **only** Browser Data from Chrome or Firefox and therefore I'll be setting up the RPi as a OpenVPN Server. I plan on following http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing as kind of a guide since I've close to no knowledge of linux or servers :)

After setting up the Server, I want to achieve, that I am able to connect to the OpenVPN Server without the Usage of a OpenVPN Client. I would like to create a private (just for my clients) Browser Extension (Chrome or Firefox) that has the key-files for authentification embedded.

The Problem is, that I have no idea how to create such a Extension and have no clue how to establish a OpenVPN Connection within the Extension to then encrypt every data transmitted within the browser.

Please note that I'm willing to use the VPN Connection for browser data only because all the other data shall use the the internet connection of the client.

Can anyone hand me a good guide or maybe even a solution for my problem? And do you think that the Openvpn Server setup like it is in the guide linked above can act as a server solution for my project?

Thank you really much for your time already!

Best regards cosi

Comment: have you found solution for that?I am looking exactly for that.

Answer (score 0):

the proper way would be with NPAPI or a protocol handler. Check google documentation on handling this.

Note, if you need to handle native code with a browser extenion, embed a small HTTP server in a native app then call by the browser extension. Allows you to pretty much code whatever you need it to do.

Stack overflow has had many discussions about these things.
connect-openvpn-in-chrome-extension

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be;

- set up comp1 to run your VPN service
- set up comp2 to connect to the VPN service as a client
- set up comp3 with a SOCKS5 proxy to comp2
- set up comp3 browser to utilize proxy

you have achieved;

- tunnel browser traffic via proxy --> vpn
- all other traffic from comp3 will go out its native network
  connection/

Not very elegant, but functional and very safe (provided your ssh and vpn services are locked down correctly)

Comment: Chrome had a "--proxy-server" command line argument, but can it be used in Windows?

Comment: i'm sure there is a way, Mozilla is what I use and have never had an issue.

Comment: sorry i misread your question. web browser's like mozilla and chrome are operating system agnostic (with few exceptions); it should work regardless of OS. I have not tried it, so i dont know for sure. but Mozilla works :)

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy

Comment: There's a big list here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension .  I tried setting --proxy-server to localhost:8080 (and host-resolver-rules), but it didn't break my browsing, so I'm not sure it worked.

Comment: I've flagged this as not an answer, however the original question shouldn't be on the site in the first place.